# Visual studio cannot compile resources (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, resources

I have a Win32 project and I needed some resource files. Specifically I have a Main.rc:

```
#include "Resources.hpp"

IDI_APP_ICON ICON "myappicon.ico"
```

and a Resources.hpp:

```
#define IDI_APP_ICON                    101
```

My dir tree is:

```
├───res
│       myappicon.ico
│       myProject.rc
│
├───src (the files below are just samples except Resources.hpp)
│       a.cpp
|       a.hpp
|       b.hpp
|       b.cpp
|       Resources.hpp
```

Everything is encoded as ANSI.

When I try to build my project from visual studio I get this error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  TrayIcon.cpp
1>  MainWindowData.cpp
1>  PopupMenu.cpp
1>  Main.cpp
1>  KbdHook.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  
1>..\..\res\myProject.rc(3): error RC2135: file not found: IDI_APP_ICON
1>  
1>  
1>..\..\res\myProject.rc(4): error RC2135: file not found: "MYAPPICO.ICO"
1>  
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

What is the problem here? I can't think of anything?

**Update:**
I changed the myProject.rc encoding to Unicode and it works. Okay, what's going on here?

And I don't want it to be Unicode. Isn't there any possible way to have it as Utf-8 or ansi??

Comment: Have you tried to tell the .rc file that .ico file is in ..\..\res\myappico.ico ?

Comment: @marom You mean put it like this `IDI_APP_ICON ICON "..\..\res\myappicon.ico"` ?? Yes, I've tried it and nothing happens.

Comment: Usually, VC++ projects have the .RC file in the same directory as the project file.  If it was me, I might try moving the .RC file up out of the res directory and then changing the path of the icon to "res\\myappicon.ico".  If you want to leave it where it is, have you tried changing the #include statement to "..\Resources.hpp" since it is not in the same directory as the .RC file?

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Yeah I tried all these. Same problem all the time.